# Spring MVC String is null when not used in input form

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Hello I have a problem with Spring input forms

for example I have User with name and password:

```
Domain object User
String name;
String password;
//getters setters
```

Some controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String info(Model model){
  User user = new User();
  user.setPassword("123");
  model.addAttribute("user", user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String info(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model){
  System.out.println(user.getPassword());   //here i get NULL
  System.out.println(user.getName());   //here i get some name
}
```

some jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
    <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value ="Add"/>
</form:form>
```

I dont want to use something like

```
<form:hidden path="password"/>
```

because that can be viewed in source code of page.

How to make data presist?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input with the password, this field wont be displayed in page, but will hold the value from the controller and carry forward to the POST controller method.

```
<form:hidden id="password" path="password"/>
```